# Texture painting not appearing in the correct area?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I am modeling a head for the first time and have come across an issue I haven't experienced before where if I paint something on my UV map it appears on a completely different area of my model.[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the direction of your face normals first.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and a few of my normals were facing the wrong way however it did not seem to be the solution to my problem.

Comment: Can you check if this problem is still the same when using another mesh with texture paint, like a monkey or cube? Also, can you show what your shader tree looks like right now, to see if maybe there is something going on with the blend mode and the material settings?